# ASP CORE: which encoding is used by asp-for for byte array (is it not base64?) and how to decode it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I've found that

`<input hidden type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Entity.RowVersion" />`

for rowVersion = `0x000000000004FAE7` encode the value as `AAAAAAAE&#x2B;uc=` .
But when I try to decode it back with `Convert.FromBase64String` I get

> System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters,

The https://base64.guru/converter/decode doesn't help to identify the algorithm.

How to decode it if not with `Convert.FromBase64String` ?

P.S. Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders package doesn't help.

Comment: You shouldn't use your entity in your view in the first place , neither you should return it directly from API endpoints. RowVersion is used for optimistic concurrency, to prevent two actions which execute at the same time overriding the other ones change and not meant to be transported to the user

Comment: The value is html encoded, `&#x2B;` means `+`, you need to html decode the value before giving it to Base64 decoding, then you get back your original bytes.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thank you. this works `Convert.FromBase64String(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(sv))` . could you create an answer?

Comment: You still shouldn't be posting the value, though. What is it that you're actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This string:

```
AAAAAAAE&#x2B;uc=
```

looks HTML encoded, as it has `&#x2B;` in there, which is an encoded `+` character.

So if you first decode it according to HTML rules, and then decode it according to Base64 rules, it should work:

```
string input = "AAAAAAAE&#x2B;uc=";
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(decoded);
string output = string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

outputs:

```
000000000004fae7
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you also give us an idea why [+] char should be escaped in an HTML attribute?

Answer (score -1):

`RowVersion` is for optimistic concurrency. It's a timestamp, so it's database-generated and should not be posted. Remove the input. You don't need it and shouldn't have it in your view.

Comment: read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application find @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RowVersion)

Comment: You just linked me to an entire document which 1) has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core and 2) says nothing about actually *posting* a value for `RowVersion`. Again, what point are you trying to make?

Comment: Once more with feeling: you're referencing a guide for ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework. Here, you're using ASP.NET Core  and EF Core. *It's a totally different framework*. That said, not sure why this guide even tells you to do that for ASP.NET MVC 5, as it still wasn't necessary then.

Comment: That's not the point. You don't need it. It doesn't do anything. It's not necessary. It's not something you should be doing anyways. Even if there was some reason in ASP.NET MVC 5 (there wasn't), that would have no application to ASP.NET Core. Just because they both support similar syntax in some cases has no bearing on anything here.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij: Well its a tutorial to show an easy example. Doesn't mean you should use it in production. Demonstrating optimistic concurrency by other means would be way more complicated in a tutorial, since (EF specific) it would require to have to different EF Context (since an entity is tracked by EF Core,its RowVersion will always be the most recent for a single instance of DbContext) and performing two requests that fast it really creates a concurrency just involves a much more complex examples. Just cause a tutorial use a hardcoded password too, doesn't mean you should do that too :P

Comment: There is nothing specific in concurency handling in asp core or classic or entity framework (rowversion of course is specific to sql server). The algorithm will be the same for php.  DbContext object is not thread safe -  save rowversion on it between requests is impossible if you do not use sessions (I do not use sessions, MS sample also). Read the tutorial. RowVersion should be saved then send together with UPDATE statement.

Comment: "Doesn't mean you should use it in production." - I should trust opinion of  random coders? I understand rowversion, I need it , I support it.